# PowerShell/CSOM - SPFeature definition is blank

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom

I'm using this [PowerShell/CSOM script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/How-to-get-the-list-of-all-735b2f95) to return a the GUIDs of the features on my SharePoint site. It works as expected, however I would like to get the name of the feature as well. Here is the example output:

[image]

Which is generated by this snippet:

[image]

I can see that these are the members of the SPFeature class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfeature_members.aspx

Am I able to use any of these to spit out the name of the feature?

Answer (score 0):

I've done it this way for our PS module.

```
Function Get-Features {
    <#
        .SYNOPSIS
        Gets all the site or web features
        .DESCRIPTION    
        Gets all the site or web scoped features of a site, useful in conjunction with Set-SiteCollectionFeature or Set-SiteFeature
        .PARAMETER Url
        The Url of the site
        .PARAMETER Scope
        The type of features being requested
        .EXAMPLE
        Can be used in variable assignment
        $features = Get-Features -Url "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/teams/eric" -Scope Site
        .EXAMPLE
        Can output a list of features
        Get-Features -Url "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/teams/eric" -Scope Web
    #>
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="The URL of the site")][ValidateNotNull()]
        [string]$Url,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="The type of features being requested")][ValidateSet("Web","Site")]
        [string]$Scope
    )
    Begin{
        $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)  
        $context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($credential.UserName, $credential.Password)

        if($Scope -eq "Web"){
            $webFeatures = $context.Web.Features
        }
        else {
            $webFeatures = $context.Site.Features
        }
        $context.Load($webFeatures)
        $context.ExecuteQuery()
    }
    Process{
        foreach($feature in $webFeatures){
            #$feature.DefinitionId
            Get-CSOMProperties -object $feature -propertyNames @("DisplayName", "DefinitionId") -executeQuery
            $feature | select DisplayName,DefinitionId   
        }
    }
    End{
        $context.Dispose()
    }
}
```

It utilizes the Get-CSOMProperties function as detailed on [ITUnity](https://www.itunity.com/article/loading-specific-values-lambda-expressions-sharepoint-csom-api-windows-powershell-1249). I believe I adapted ours from the article you reference.

Comment: Hi Eric, getting this error:  The term 'Get-CSOMProperties' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet. Any ideas?

Comment: I've looked at the ITUnity page and I'm unsure of what snippet I need to put inside a new function called 'Get-CSOMProperties '. Any ideas?

Comment: For Get-CSOMProperties he references above, look at "Load-CSOMProperties" on this guy's github: 
https://github.com/benstegink/PowerShellScripts/blob/master/Office365/Load-CSOMProperties.ps1

Sourcing: benstegink for saving the script to github and originally Gary LaPointe on ITUnity